# find field $in an array of embedded docs?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

What's the correct syntax for finding all docs where, in an array of embedded docs, the username is 'User1'?

These variations have yet to work:

```
db.collection.find( { to: { username: { $in: [ "User1" ] } } } )
db.collection.find( { to: { $in: [ { username: "User1" } ] } } )
```

The docs look like:

```
{
    "message" : "Here's a Message",
    "to" : [
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("53aada6f8b10eb0000ec8a90"),
            "username" : "User1",
            "updated" : ISODate("2014-06-28T19:14:20Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("53af140c14809099b615d347"),
            "read" : {
                "marked" : false
            }
        }
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("53aada6f8b10eb0000ec8a91"),
            "username" : "User2",
            "updated" : ISODate("2014-06-28T19:15:20Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("53af140c14809099b615d348"),
            "read" : {
                "marked" : false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to access elements of an array. The correct syntax is:

```
db.collection.find({"to.username": { $in: ["User1"] }});
```

The [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator is used when you're looking for multiple values. 
If you're searching with only one value the more efficient query is a simple equality check:

```
db.collection.find({"to.username": "User1"});
```